# Float Right Pushing Label Text Up

Tags: html, css

I will start off by describing what I am looking to accomplish. I have a page on which I have a fieldset that contains a div of a label and two buttons. I would like the label to be aligned to the left while the buttons are both aligned to the right. I have attempted to do this but I am finding the result to be a little different than what I need and I am lacking the understanding of why after hacking at it for some time.

Here is my HTML:

```
<fieldset class="main">
    <div class="inner clearfix">
      <label id="label1">Successfully Completed!</label>
                    <button type="button" class="dbBtn" id="dbCopyNewDb">Proceed</button>
                    <button type="button" class="dbBtn" id="dbCopyRestart">Start Over</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

and here is my css:

```
.main {
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 30px;
}
.dbBtn{
  float: right;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

I noticed that when I float my buttons to the right my text gets pushed up slightly. While this may seem minuscule it is noticeable enough that I would prefer to find a way to correct this and truly vertical align my label and buttons in the middle of the div.

I attempted to use `text-align right` instead of `float: right` and `vertical-align: middle` in order to put my label in the middle of my div but these seem to do nothing. I have tried looking at other SO posts but the solutions did not work for me. How can I accomplish what I have set out to do and more importantly what am I doing incorrectly/overlooking in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good opportunity to use `CSS Flexbox`.

- `justify-content: flex-end` means the child elements will be oriented towards the right of `.inner`.
- `flex: 1 0 50%` means that the `label` will occupy *at least* `50%` of `.inner` and can grow to whatever space is available, left of the two buttons.

**Working Example:**

```css
.inner {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
align-items: center;
padding: 0 3px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
height: 30px;
}

label {
flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.dbBtn {
margin: 0 0 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="main">
<div class="inner">
<label id="label1">Successfully Completed!</label>
<button type="button" class="dbBtn" id="dbCopyNewDb">Proceed</button>
<button type="button" class="dbBtn" id="dbCopyRestart">Start Over</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works exactly the way you want except without using `float` at all. Try out the snippet below:

```css
.main {
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="main">
    <div class="inner clearfix">
      <label id="label1">Successfully Completed!</label>
      <div class="right">
        <button type="button" class="dbBtn" id="dbCopyNewDb">Proceed</button>
        <button type="button" class="dbBtn" id="dbCopyRestart">Start Over</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I basically just put both buttons in a `div` and pushed the div to 5 pixels from the right of the containing box, and 50% from the top of the containing box, and then used `transform: translateY(-50%)` to push the buttons back up by 50% of their height so it is perfectly vertically centered. It seems to work and looks good in the snippet above.

I'm not sure how you would do this with `float: right`, but this is the way I would accomplish it. Hope this helps!

Comment: I forgot to do the same thing to the label, I'll fix that. Basically, do the same thing that I did to the buttons to the label and it will be the answer.

Comment: Fixed - the answer now vertically center-aligns both the label and the buttons, and puts the buttons on the right while keeping the label on the left. Hope this helped!